# How to configure AdMob publisher account for in-app ads

Tags: android, admob, adsense

When I've registered as a Google Developer to publish my first app, I've registered myself also on AdMob, but then I did not use it anymore.. Now I'm thinking about adding AdMob ads' views to my app and following the Google guides they mention that you have to register as publisher on AdMob... Is this publisher subscription the one I've done at the first time or do I have to do something particular in order to become a publisher? If I implement AdMob ads and then AdMob must pay me for clicks received from my app, I'll receive funds on the AdMob account and then I'll find options to retrieve my money?

**EDIT:** If it is necessary to register your app in AdMob, what should I put in the required field *company name* since I'm not working on android for any company and I'm developing in my free time? Can I sell apps or use AdMob?

Comment: see admob faq :: http://support.google.com/admob/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1619834

Comment: I've seen that the page you've linked points you to AdSense, where I have a publisher-ID defined.. Are AdMob and AdSense connected, i.e. when I implement AdMob ads I'll receive funds on my AdSense account? I'm sorry if I made a bit of confusion, I'm just trying to understand..

Answer (score 3):

I am doing the following :

- login to admob (admob.com) with my Google account
- setup the admob publisher account (to get the publisher id) and declare the different apps
- put an AdView in the app by following the admob implementation guides and best practices : [admob best practices](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/bestpractices)

Comment: Where do you setup a publisher account in admob? I thought that declaring apps in admob was only required to start advertising champaigns for your apps and not to insert admob ads in your apps.. Then, as I asked in a comment above, is AdSense connected to admob? On AdSense it says I have a publisher account, since I can see my publisher ID.

Comment: If I understood correctly, if you are developping a native application (not a web site for mobiles), your application will receive ads from adsense (when it will be correctly registered inside admob and accepted by Google as an adsense target)

Comment: Is it necessary to have a company in order to sell apps on Google Play or become an AdMob target? I'm asking this because they asks you for your company name, which is a required field, but I do not own or belong to any company when working on my Android projects.. I don't know if I can simply put a fake company name, because it could be illegal... any idea about that?

Comment: I don't think Google will check your company name (but maybe I am wrong). The problem for you is to be safe with your country laws ...

Answer (score 0):

The company name should be the name you are using as a developer if you dont work for any company at all.  As an example if you are using the developer name "yourappsdev" you can set the company name as "yourappsdev".